# Get top ranked values across multiple fields

Tags: sql

Imagine a table that has three fields, a unique user ID and two non-unique traits (eg age, sex, etc): user / traitA / traitB

In this table I want to pull the most frequent value for each trait in a single query.  If our traits were School Year / Major then a result could be: Junior / Biology.  Note, this does NOT mean Juniors in Biology are the most common combination, just that each value itself is most common in its trait.

This is obviously possible running two separate queries, grouping by a single fields and putting a rank and having combo in.  But my specific problem has more fields and the cost to do subsequent queries is expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting single most common *trait*:

SELECT age
FROM table_name
GROUP BY age
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1

To select most common values from multiple columns this query worked in Postgre:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    FIRST_VALUE(age) OVER (ORDER BY count1 DESC) AS top1,
    FIRST_VALUE(sex) OVER (ORDER BY count2 DESC) AS top2
    FROM (
        SELECT age,
               sex,
               COUNT(age) OVER (PARTITION BY age) AS count1,
               COUNT(sex) OVER (PARTITION BY sex) AS count2
               FROM some_table
    ) some_table
```

Comment: Please read the whole question.
"This is <i>obviously</i> possible running two separate queries"

Comment: This smells like the right answer, but I think I'm a bit stuck.  In your table what is name/time (I'm assuming they are unique, this is a table of people: name/time loaded/age/sex)?

Comment: I've borrowed a public table on holidays by country as an easy experiment (https://modeanalytics.com/scottieb/reports/cf97b9a78035).  I'm not able to get the right answer but I think I'm mis-using the subquery you set up.

Comment: @ScottieB oh sorry I forgot to edit that part. It's from my own table and is irrelevent. It should be age,sex. I've tried with your table and it returns Tue,India as top pair.

Comment: Works like a charm, this is exactly what I was hoping to find!